# Ajax event doesn't work when using grid layout in panelGrid

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu, responsiveness, panelgrid

In the code bellow, when I define the attribute `layout="grid"` for panelGrid, the ajax event of "periodo Letivo" doesn't work. It should load "cadeira" component. If I remove the layout attribute, It works fine, but I lost the responsiveness.

If someone can help me, thanks.

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" style="border:0px !important; background:none;" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank ui-fluid">
    <p:outputLabel for="periodoLetivo" value="Período letivo" />
    <p:selectOneMenu id="periodoLetivo"
        value="#{viewForm.periodoLetivo}"
        converter="#{genericConverter}" immediate="true"
        required="true">

        <f:selectItem itemLabel="[-SELECIONE-]"
            noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{periodosLetivos}" var="periodoLetivo"
            itemLabel="#{periodoLetivo.nome}" itemValue="#{periodoLetivo}" />
        <p:ajax event="change" update="cadeira" process="periodoLetivo" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:outputLabel for="cadeira" value="Disciplina" />
    <p:selectOneMenu id="cadeira" value="#{viewForm.cadeira}"
        converter="#{genericConverter}" required="true">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="[-SELECIONE-]"
            noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{viewForm.cadeiras}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: where is the layout? Where is the layout tag?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post. I mean: layout = "grid"

Comment: Off-Topic: 'layout' is an attribute, not a tag

Comment: Are we talking about my text or about the code?

Comment: text, I corrected it

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue replacing `<p:ajax event="change" update="cadeira" process="periodoLetivo" />` by this `<f:ajax event="change" render="cadeira"></f:ajax>`.